# Pandas DataFrame Logic - Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, logic

Trying to backtest trading logic for fun but I can seem to comprehend how to utilize numpy to make decisions.  For example, I want to set df['position'] = 1 or -1 based on whether the data is below or above the upper and lower lines. If Data <= the lower line I want to set position = 1 and keep it at 1 until Data it is >= the upper line.  Once data is >= the upper line I want to set position = -1 and keep at -1 then repeat.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.standard_normal((5, 100)).flatten()
data = data.cumsum()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': data})
df['std'] = df['Data'].rolling(50).std()
df['SMA'] = df['Data'].rolling(50).mean()
df['upper'] = df['SMA'] + (2 * df['std'])
df['lower'] = df['SMA'] - (2 * df['std'])

df[['Data', 'SMA', 'upper', 'lower']].plot(figsize=(10, 6))

df['position'] = 0
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here I try to do just that but fail because I don't know how to do this properly.

```
df['islower'] = np.where(df['Data'] < df['lower'], 1, 0)
df['isupper'] = np.where(df['Data'] > df['upper'], 1, 0)
df['position'] = np.where(df['isupper']==1, -1, 0) | np.where(df['islower']==1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: What do you mean that you fail? What's the error you get? Or do you want to show the data you get out?

Comment: I can't figure out how to set df['position'] = 1 if df['Data'] < df['lower'] and df['position'] = -1 if df['Data'] > df['upper'].  I can do this with state logic without pandas but the goal is to do this with a dataframe.

Comment: Isn't the answer below what you are looking for? If not, I suggest you show the output you would like to get versus the output you actually get

Comment: By the way, notice that both `numpy` and `pandas` both have a `where` function. I think what you are looking for is the one from `pandas`

Comment: Yes, this shows how to properly tell if data is below or above the lines but how do I set position = 1 or -1 if we touched the bottom/top line?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is:

```
df['islower'] = df['islower'].where(df['Data'] < df['lower'], 1, 0)    
df['isupper'] = df['isupper'].where(df['Data'] < df['upper'], 1, 0)
```

Comment: Yes, this shows how to properly tell if data is below or above the lines but how do I set position = 1 or -1 if we touched the bottom/top line?

Comment: Isn't that what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to figure out how to set df['position'] = np.where(df['isupper']==1, -1, 0) | np.where(df['islower']== 1, 1, 0) The code that I am using is not correct if you df[['position']].plot(figsize=(10, 6)) and see the results

Comment: you mean how to have an OR condition?

Comment: I guess, i'm not sure if that is the best method for setting position = 1 or -1 when looking at df['islower'] and df['isupper']

Comment: Sorry, you are not clear. Your code is working? What the matter exactly>?

Comment: Think of position as buy or sell based whether its 1 or -1.  I want to buy low and sell high.  So I set position 1 (Buy) when the data is near the lower line.  Then I set position to -1 (Sell) when the data is near the top line.

Comment: I don't care about the application. What in your code is not working?

Comment: The logic I am using for setting position is incorrect.........df['position'] = np.where(df['isupper']==1, -1, 0) | np.where(df['islower']==1, 1, 0)  It only looks at the first df['isupper'] and sets position based on that only